# Создание каталогов товаров на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Стоит задача создать каталог на WordPress, с этим проблем нет, однако, существует проблема следующего характера: создаю новый тип записи, например catalog (register_post_type), и таксономию к нему types (register_taxonomy). Теперь разберемся с ссылками: записи доступны по ссылкам site.ru/catalog, а их категории по ссылке site.ru/types. Но правильным было бы одинаковые ссылки на сами товары и их категории. (site.ru/категория_товаров/товар) Как их объединить?

Comment: Непонятно с чем проблема. Не знаешь как связать таксономию с типом постов или что?  И не указано какие правила пермалинков настроены

Comment: Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы категории товаров и товары были доступны по ссылкам site.ru/catalog/. Пермалинки настроены так: /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Ну так оно и будет если сделать всё правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, очень наглядно.